# What is "multi" in Webpack's output?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-3

Webpack is outputting something like

```
[78] multi ./src/index.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
```

What does the `multi` on this line mean?

Answer (score 1):

**multi** means multi-file, in other words the **multiple webpack entries as an array**.

Depends on the entry object, webpack, internally has different approach to handle it. When entry is an array, then [MultiEntryPlugin.js](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/028c51301733836abbedc88be7483af2623f5943/lib/MultiEntryPlugin.js) is called.

That is the internal flow to follow:

[WebpackOptionsApply](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/215647d9fcf2cfa69c83b3721ae7058ccd31d851/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js) >

[EntryOptionPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/028c51301733836abbedc88be7483af2623f5943/lib/EntryOptionPlugin.js) >

1. [SingleEntryPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/028c51301733836abbedc88be7483af2623f5943/lib/SingleEntryPlugin.js), if entry is **object**
2. [MultiEntryPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/028c51301733836abbedc88be7483af2623f5943/lib/MultiEntryPlugin.js), if entry is **array**
3. [DynamicEntryPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/028c51301733836abbedc88be7483af2623f5943/lib/DynamicEntryPlugin.js), if entry is **function**

You can see the test case here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/v3.4.1/test/binCases/entry/multi-file